# Android cannot get properly a String with " . " in the value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried to retrieve a String Value that contains decimal numbers for example "3.5". when trying to retrieve them to android, they move with quotations marks, but when passing a String that contains a number without decimals or without a point that does not happen, some idea without having to pass a int to the database or without convert "rates" value to int?

in this way I try to get the String "rates" value from the database

```
 String rating = (String) dataSnapshot.child("rates").getValue();
 int ratingint = Integer.valueOf(rating);
```

The error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "3.5"
```

this is defined in the database

[image: rates: "3.5"]

Comment: Real question is why are you saving `double` values as `String` in database because each conversion ea. `valueOf` is unnecessary new object allocation when you can store `double` value directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
 int ratingint = Integer.valueOf(rating);
```

into this:

```
 double ratingint = Double.valueOf(rating);
```

Check the docs for more information:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking that the problem was because of the quotation marks

Answer (score 1):

An `Integer` can only store (and therefore parse) whole numbers. You're trying to parse a decimal number, which is not possible directly due to the lack of support for floating points on integer values.

You probably want to parse it as a `Double` or a `Float` instead. If you really need it to be an `int`, you can then round that decimal number into an integer with a few different math functions.